# Android temperature permission

Tags: android, permissions, sensors, android-sensors, temperature

I need to keep track of the temperature using my my mobile phone. I wrote this:

```
    SensorManager mySensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    AmbientTemperatureSensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
    if(AmbientTemperatureSensor != null){
        txtTemperature.setText("Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE Available");
        mySensorManager.registerListener(
                AmbientTemperatureSensorListener,
                AmbientTemperatureSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }else{
        txtTemperature.setText("Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE NOT Available");
    }
```

It always says that it is not available, whichever device I use.

Do I need to use a permission? I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It always says that it is not available, whichever device I use.

Those devices do not have ambient temperature sensors, then. This is not surprising.

> Do I need to use a permission?

Not that I am aware of.

Comment: yes thanks, it was weird 'cause I was also trying on a galaxy s6 after I read the s4 has such sensor, but apparently ONLY the s4 has it, and I think some sort of Tab3 version. Thanks anyway